# What is the else part in this code mean?

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I was browsing some embedded programming link 
http://www.micromouseonline.com/2016/02/02/systick-configuration-made-easy-on-the-stm32/

*<sub>[Note that the author of the code at the above link has since updated the code, and the `delay_ms()` implementation in the article no longer uses the solution shown below.]</sub>*

and ended up with this following code. This is for ARM architecture but basically this is a function which will cause a delay of certain milliseconds passed as a parameter. So I could understand the if condition but why is the else condition necessary here? can someone please explain it to me?

```
void delay_ms (uint32_t t)
{
  uint32_t start, end;
  start = millis();//This millis function will return the system clock in 
                   //milliseconds
  end = start + t;
  if (start < end) {
     while ((millis() >= start) && (millis() < end))
     { // do nothing } 
  }
 else{
     while ((millis() >= start) || (millis() < end)) 
     {
      // do nothing
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: You should cite your source - so we might avoid it.  That code is awful, and demonstrates a lack of understanding of fundamental principles.

Comment: I agree this is pretty bad, I would avoid other code from this person.  It is a good idea esp with code like this to sample the function one time then use the sampled variable.  As the time can change as you are walking through this code.  Sometimes code like this is for timeouts and you want to know or show the timestamp and if you sample again you again can have a different time, so if nothing else  this should be more of a while(1)  { x=millis() then if greater or less than then break.

Comment: it is broken in other ways as well.  "lack of understanding of fundamental principles" about sums it up.

Comment: @klutt : Not that I have published on the Internet as an example to others!  If this were Hago's own code, I'd be less harsh; but this is "found code" that he appears to be attempting to learn from.  What is really funny/worrying is the careful comment on the arguably obvious function of millis(), but no comment on the parts that clearly need it.

Comment: @Clifford, I apologize. By trying to understand the original code, I felt that something is unclear and wanted to know more about it. Thanks everyone for your valuable comments.

Comment: In the the code at the link you have now posted, the else block is commented out, not as you have it; the author does not explain that and passes it off as necessary complexity to deal with roll-over - he is wrong, and I am pretty sure the code is too - with or without the else.

Comment: Note the article you linked accepts comments; you could have asked the author for an explanation.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, I was kidding a bit. Removed that comment now. Sorry for the noise, and you're completely right.

Comment: @old_timer "lack of fundamental principles"... which ones? While I myself am rather quick at condemning bad code, the above example is not in the only-touch-it-with-a-long-pole class IMHO. Ok, it has the flaw to hang forever for t==0 (which could be corrected cheaply) but the conditions themselves could be interpreted as a clever play with sequence points to simplify the inner loop.

Comment: Just agreeing with Clifford, this is basic understanding of binary math as implemented in processors.  if t ==  0, yeah thats a bug.

Comment: I commented on the article that you have now cited, and he has since updated the article with my solution.

Comment: @Vroomfondel : "simplify the inner loop"!?  Nothing is simplified here, and there is no inner loop. The "fundamental principles" I referred to are modulo 2^n arithmetic, and comparison of _interval passed_ not absolute time - as exemplified in my answer.  Besides, I asked the original author, and he agrees it was broken and has since fixed it.

Comment: To be fair to the [original author](http://www.micromouseonline.com/2016/02/02/systick-configuration-made-easy-on-the-stm32), he has fixed the code in his article, and in its context (how to use Cortex-M systick counter), I have no particular objections, and the article need not avoided it as I suggested previously.

Answer (score 5):

If `start + t` caused an overflow, `end` will be less than `start`, so the `if` part deals with that, and the `else` with the "normal" case.

To be honest, it would take some thinking about to determine whether it is actually correct, but it is hardly worth it since it is a somewhat over-complicated means of solving a simple problem.  All that is needed is the following:

```
void delay_ms( uint32_t t )
{
    uint32_t start = millis() ;

    while( (uint32_t)millis() - start < t )
    { 
        // do nothing 
    } 
}
```

To understand how this works imagine `start` is `0xFFFFFFFF`, and `t` is `0x00000002`, after two milliseconds, `millis()` will be `0x00000001`, and `millis() - start` will be `2`.

The loop will terminate when `millis() - start == 3`. Arguably you might prefer `millis() - start <= t`, but then the delay will be between `t-1` to `t` milliseconds rather than *at least* `t` milliseconds (`t` to `t+1`).  Your choice, but the point is that you should compare calculate and compare *time periods* rather then trying to compare the absolute timestamp values - much simpler.

Comment: As far as I can see, `millis` returns an `unsigned long` so it might be a good idea to cast it just to be on the safe side. This, on the other hand, also would be a good idea in the original code.

Comment: @klutt : yes I originally included advice on casting (see edit history), but there is the possibility that it could return a `short` - unlikely but the permutations seemed somewhat off topic.  It is not a standard function and we have only the comment to indicate its semantics on the specific platform in question.  As it happens on ARM `unsigned long` is 32 bit in any case.

Comment: I just thought that in the future, MAYBE an ARM unsigned long would be 64 bits, and then this (and the original code) would fail.

Comment: @klutt - it is a fair point, on ARM64 it could be either. I had deciced to assume that `uint32_t` was chosen for type agreement with `millis()`, but given the poor quality of the original solution, that is not a given. Fixed.

Comment: Haha, a bit overkill maybe, but better safe than sorry. However, I must point out that if millis returned a short, casting it to uint32_t would not help. Imagine a t higher than the max value of short.

Comment: @klutt I agree which is why I originally chose to ignore the issue - until you mentioned it, but it is perhaps fair to assume that `uint32_t` was chosen for good reason.  Basically the type of `millis()` must be at least as wide as the type of `start` - not an unreasonable constraint.

Comment: @Clifford, removed my comments and instead posted an as usual long winded answer...

Answer (score 3):

Note that the second while loop has `||` instead of `&&`. This is to handle overflow. What happens if `start + t` is a bigger number than `end` can hold? The answer is that you will get an *overflow*. When you add 1 to an unsigned integer that holds its maximum value, it overflows to 0.

Here is a short snippet to show the effects of overflow:

```
uint8_t c = 255;
uint8_t d = c+1;
printf("%d %d", c, d);
```

This will print `255 0`

This overflow is not even an unlikely scenario in this case. The maximum value an `uint32_t` can hold is approx 4*10⁹. That is the amount of milliseconds that passes in 46 days.

Here is a code snippet to test it yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
uint32_t s = -2; // Initialize s to it's maximum number
                 // minus one via overflow
uint32_t e, t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    e = s+t;
    if(s<e) 
        printf("foo\n");
    else
        printf("bar\n");
}
```

And when I run it with different inputs:

```
$ ./a.out 
0
bar

$ ./a.out 
1
foo
```

However, the code is awful. See [Cliffords answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51295210/6699433) for an explanation why.

Comment: you mean outside the integer range? like above  2 ^ 32?

Comment: @hago Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: but it looks the if condition could fail, that is start can be greater than end? how can that be possible?  The variable start is going to store always the current time and end will be the current time added to the required delay. So start can't be always greater than end is my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

This code is trying to deal with the rollover.  Take an 8 bit counter/timer counts up lets say from 0x00 to 0xFF then rolls over to 0x00 again.  If I want to use this timer to wait 16 timer ticks (0x10) (using polling) and when I start that delay the timer is at 0x1B, then I want to wait for 0x1B+0x10 = 0x2B.
Start = 0x1B, end = 0x2B, for the values 0x1B, 0x1C 0x1D...0x29, 0x2A we want to delay, start is less than end so there is no counter rollover in this code so long as t is not larger than the timer which it cant be we assume based on this code, so:

```
while((now>=start)&&(now<end)) continue;
```

Where now is sampled in that loop (while((millis()>=start).

As you pointed out, lets say

start = 0xF5, all the variables are the same size, 32 bits, mine they
are all 8 for this demonstration so 0xF5 + 0x10 = 0x05, end = 0x05  so we want to delay while now is 0xF5, 0xF6, 0xF7, 0xF8...0xFF 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04.  So we we have to split cases we have to cover, now >= start to cover the 0xF5 to 0xFF and now

while((now>=start)||(now

But as Clifford has pointed out, fundamental programming knowledge, some of the magic of twos complement the now being the first number (0xFD to 0x05):

```
(0xFD - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x08
(0xFE - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x09
(0xFF - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x0A
(0x00 - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x0B
(0x01 - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x0C
(0x02 - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x0D
(0x03 - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x0E
(0x04 - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x0F
(0x05 - 0xF5) & 0xFF = 0x10
```

Works perfect, we just need to subtract now - start for an up counter and mask the math to the size of the counter and/or variables whichever is smaller

while(((now-start)&0xFF)

For a downcounter use start - now.

The author of that code was trying to deal with the rollover without understanding twos complement.  Back in the day before I learned this my code was even worse I was probably computing the math for the number of counts before the rollover then the number of counts after, whatever didnt last long I convinced myself that the rollover math works so long as you mask it right.

NOW SAYING THAT

If your timer does NOT rollover between all ones to all zeros or all zeros to all ones, which many microcontroller timers can be programmed to do and you are not using the timers features completely then the above wont work.  If you have an 8 bit timer and it counts from 0x00 to 0x53 then rolls over to 0x00, because that is how you set it for some reason, or you are re-using a timer that you have set for a periodic interrupt as a polled timer,  then you have to do in a better way, what the author of that code did:

while(now<0x53) continue;
while(now>end) continue;

sampling now each loop.

But the math for end does not roll over naturally you have to compute end as

```
end = start + t; 
if(end>0x53) end = end - 0x54;
```

In that case though one would have to wonder why you are using a timer like that for polled timeouts, use a timer that counts all the bits and rolls over for polled timeouts use a timer that counts to N or counts to zero from N for regular periodic interrupts or can poll those as well, but in that case you are not doing generic delays necessarily....well...you could...set the timer to one millisecond, then count the rollover flags until you get to t.  Easier than the now - start math. and can count as high as you want.

Millis() puts an abstraction layer between you and the timer though and we assume that millis rolls over from all ones to all zeros.

if you have a timer that counts from 0x00000000 to 0x55555555 for example and rolls over you also cannot clip it to try to get this math to work

```
while(((start-now)&0xFFFF)<t) continue;
```

that wont work because there is a point where 0xXXXX5555 rolls to 0xXXXX0000 giving you a short count that one time.

This shortcut of while(((start-now)&mask)

Otherwise you have to do something like the code you found with some modifications.

I also recommend as a habit not to sample the timer multiple times.  I have seen this bug all to often:

```
while((timer()-start)<timeout)
{
    if(read_register(n)&0x10) break;
}
if((timer()-start)>=timeout)
{
   printf("Timed out\n");
   return 1;
} 
return 0;
```

Perhaps because the same coworker would implement it over and over again...

You want to sample the timer once for both use cases, if you re-sample it later
it may result in a different time.  The condition may have passed within the timeout but then re-sampling the timer now times out.

instead something like

```
while(1)
{
   delta=timer()-start;
   if(delta>t) break;
   if(register_read(n)&0x10) break;
}
if(delta>t) 
{
   printf(...
   return 1;
}
return 0;
```

For the same reason you cant necessarily go back and read the register again to see if it was the reason why the loop was broken.  Depends on that register.

And yes some folks may hate the coding style here, and consider that a bug too, point was minimize the number of times you sample the timer if you are re-using that timestamp more than once, in the case of the code you posted as written it is okay as C is supposed to evaluate left to right

```
millis() >= start
then
millis() < end
```

had it been written

```
 while ((millis() < end) && (millis() >= start))
 while ((millis() < end) || (millis() >= start))
```

for start

for the start>end case if the first read is less than end and it increments so it
is equal to or larger than end for the second read to compare to start, then same
deal you have to loop again to catch millis() not less than end.

So it is an extra sample but works fine.  The code could have been simplified to

```
if(start<end)
{
   while(millis()<end) continue;
}
else
{
   while(millis()>=start) continue;
   while(millis()<end) continue;
}
```

sampling once per loop.

And also note this kind of polled timer only works if you are for the most part outrunning the timer with your polling loop, you dont have interrupts that take a long time to bump you another rollover of the timer.  If you are not sampling that fast, then you might want to put a limit on the size of t, make it so it cant be more than half the number of bits in the timer.  How much you should limit it depends on how fast you can sample this thing.

Polled time loops should only be used for at that time or greater, if you want to time a specific amount of time the delay may run long unless you are careful, if you have interrupts or other things you may run long, maybe very long.  So if you want to time say at least 10ms but 100ms now and again is okay, like bit banging i2c or spi, thats fine.  But if you are trying to bit bang a uart a polled timer might not be the best way to go, depends on your system design.

Comment: What are you on about two's complement for? The code uses uint32_t and there's no implicit promotions to signed type. Two's complement is therefore completely irrelevant here, as no signed numbers exist in the code. Also, every raw timer/rtc counter I have ever seen in a microcontroller rolls over from 2^16 to 0 or 2^32 to 0, without caring the slightest about signed number representations.

Comment: twos complement is what makes the math work when wrapping around all ones to all zeros and vice versa.  the subtraction works if you clip the numbers, all part of the magic of twos complement.

Comment: logic in the processor for addition and subtraction is based on twos complement math, a subtraction is implemented using an adder, based on twos complement math.

Comment: if you dont want it called twos complement and just simple base two math thats fine...

Comment: @Lundin a high percentage of the cortex-ms have a 24 bit systick timer (if they have one compiled in basically).  Have you not tried a cortex-m based mcu?